# I'm trying to make a discord bot that web scrapes a random Wikipedia article, but after you try it once, it repeats the same thing

Tags: python, discord

As the title says, im trying to make a discord bot that webscrapes a random Wikipedia page. I'm currently having trouble as the Discord bot will repeat the same page after you run the command for the page once. I'm assuming this has something to do with a loop but im not sure.

````
import requests
import webbrowser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import discord 
import random
#-----------------------------

#Var's
TOKEN = '#Not gonna show'

wiki_url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random"

article_page = requests.get(wiki_url)


client = discord.Client() 

soup = BeautifulSoup(article_page.text, "html.parser")

article_title = soup.find(id='firstHeading')
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#Func's
@client.event 
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    username = str(message.author).split('#')[0]
    user_message = str(message.content)
    channel = (message.channel.name)
    print(f'{username}: {user_message} ({channel})')

    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.channel.name == 'bot':
        if user_message.lower() == 'hello wikibot':
            await message.channel.send(f'Hello {username}!')
            return
        elif user_message.lower == 'bye wikibot':
            await message.channel.send(f'See you later {username}!')
        while user_message.lower() == '!random wiki':
            response = f'The title of the Random article is:, {article_title.string}'
            await message.channel.send(response)
            break
            
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------


client.run(TOKEN)```
````

Comment: Think about this: At what point do you make an HTTP request to the Wikipedia page? Should you be making multiple requests? And when/where?

Comment: @PaulM. On line 19 where all the variables are

Comment: Right, you only make a single request to that URL as soon as the script runs. You also only ever set `soup` and `article_title` once at the start of the program, so it's no surprise that these variables don't change. You'll have to make a new request to that URL every time you want a new page - you'll also have to re-parse the response of those requests with BeautifulSoup, and pull out the new article title each time.

Comment: @PaulM. I'm sorry if this is dumb, but how would I exactly do this? I'm new to coding and don't know much.

Comment: No worries, there are no dumb questions. I'll post an answer in a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change this:

```
while user_message.lower() == '!random wiki':
    response = f'The title of the Random article is:, {article_title.string}'
    await message.channel.send(response)
    break
```

Into:

```
elif user_message.lower() == "!random wiki":

    article_page = requests.get(wiki_url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(article_page.text, "html.parser")
    article_title = soup.find(id='firstHeading')
    
    response = f'The title of the Random article is:, {article_title.string}'
    await message.channel.send(response)
```

That way, you're getting a new random page each time the user message is `!random wiki`.

I would also remove the original `article_page`, `soup` and `article_title` variables from the top of your code.